# Can´t bind [checked] Mat-Radio-Button with the values on its formControlName (Auto complete)

Tags: angular, binding, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms, checked

I'm trying to autocomplete a form using the progress from previous responses the user gave. I get a JSON with the previous responses. In my component I build the form using '?' knowing the json with the results could be null

```
this.b2Data = this.surveyServices.getSurvey(); // Gets a JSON with results for this particular form

      this.b2Data = this.formGroup.group({
        ambExclusivos: new UntypedFormControl(this.b2Data?.ambExclusivos),
        ambDormir: new UntypedFormControl(this.b2Data?.ambDormir, Validators.pattern(NUMERIC_PATTERN)),
        ambTrabajo: new UntypedFormControl(this.b2Data?.ambTrabajo),
        numAmbTrabajo:new UntypedFormControl(this.b2Data?.numAmbTrabajo, Validators.pattern(NUMERIC_PATTERN)),
        ambComplementarioCocina: new UntypedFormControl(this.b2Data?.ambComplementarioCocina),
        cocinaEnergia: new UntypedFormControl(this.b2Data?.cocinaEnergia),
})
```

In my HTML

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <form [formGroup]="b2Data" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

                <mat-form-field class="full-width-input" appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>1. ¿Cuántos ambientes/habitaciones tiene este hogar para su uso exclusivo? (excluyendo cocina, baño, pasillos, lavadero, garage)</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="ambExclusivos" placeholder="" value="{{b2Data.ambExclusivos}}">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="b2Data.controls.ambExclusivos?.errors">
                        Por favor ingrese caracteres numéricos (números positivos sin decimales).
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field class="full-width-input" appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>2. De esos, ¿cuántos usan habitualmente para dormir?</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="ambDormir"placeholder="" value="{{b2Data.ambExclusivos}}">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="b2Data.controls.ambDormir?.errors">
                        Por favor ingrese caracteres numéricos (números positivos sin decimales).
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <p>3. ¿Utiliza alguno exclusivamente como lugar de trabajo? (para consultorio, estudio, taller, negocio, etc.)</p>
                <section class="example-section">
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="ambTrabajo" name="ambTrabajo" >
                        <mat-radio-button name="si" color="accent" matInput value = "true" ng-dirty
                            [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.ambTrabajo === true">Sí</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button matInput value="false"
                            [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.ambTrabajo === false">No</mat-radio-button>
                    </mat-radio-group>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="b2Data.controls.ambTrabajo.errors">
                        El campo es requerido.
                    </mat-error>
                </section>
                <mat-form-field  *ngIf="b2Data.value.ambTrabajo === 'true'" style="width: 15rem" appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>3. a) ¿Cuántos?</mat-label>
                    <input type= "number" matInput formControlName="numAmbTrabajo" placeholder="" value = "{{b2Data.numAmbComplemTrabajo}}">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="b2Data.controls.numAmbTrabajo?.errors">
                        Por favor ingrese caracteres numéricos (números positivos sin decimales).
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <p>4. ¿Tiene además...</p>
                    <section class="example-section">
                        <mat-radio-group formControlName="ambComplementarioCocina" name="ambComplementarioCocina" aria-label="">a) ...cuarto de cocina?
                            <mat-radio-button matInput value="true"
                                [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.ambComplementarioCocina === true">Sí</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button matInput value="false"
                                [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.ambComplementarioCocina === false">No</mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="b2form.controls.ambComplementarioCocina?.errors?.required">
                            El campo es requerido.
                        </mat-error>
                    </section>

 <p>8. ¿Para cocinar, utiliza principalmente ...</p>
                <section class="example-section">
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="cocinaEnergia" name="energy" aria-label="Entrevista realizada">
                        <mat-radio-button [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.cocinaEnergia === 'Gas de red'" matInput value="Gas de red">... Gas de red?</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.cocinaEnergia === 'Gas de tubo/ garrafa'" matInput value="Gas de tubo/ garrafa" >... Gas de tubo/ garrafa?</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.cocinaEnergia === 'Kerosene/ leña/ carbón'" matInput value="Kerosene/ leña/ carbón" >... Kerosene/ leña/ carbón?</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button [checked] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.cocinaEnergia === 'Otro'" matInput value="Otro">... Otro</mat-radio-button>
                    </mat-radio-group>
                </section>
                <mat-form-field *ngIf="b2form.value.cocinaEnergia === 'Otro'"style="width: 90%" appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Especificar aquí</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="energyEsp" id="especify" [(ngModel)] = "b2Data !== null && b2Data.energyEsp">
                </mat-form-field>
```

But I can´t get the mat radio buttons checked using the values inside the results JSON.

I have tried to bind [checked] using the condition where the results JSON (b2Data) is not null and where the value b2data.*anyGivenField* matchs the radio button value. Note that the first, second and last form fields (type number, type number and type enum) works.

Any thoughts, recomendations? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello 
I've create a demo in order to demonstrate a solution. Could you check, if it resolves your issue, I will add an answer
Here is the Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylry2g?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Hi, Nikita. I already solved the problem just using the JSON.stringify method for every mat radio group formControlName. That's because the b2Data.ambTrabajo, b2Data.ambComplementarioCocina retrieves a boolean value which would never match the form control type string. Thank you very much. I will post the code soon.